# Setting a color theme on Vim

Tags: vim, linux-mint

I've updated vim to its latest release (8.1.39) and I'm still not able to have a color theme working. I've downloaded [`atom.vim`](https://github.com/gregsexton/Atom/blob/master/colors/atom.vim) to `~/.vim/colors`. Note: in my Ubuntu install it's working just fine.

And my `~/.vimrc` is as follows:

```
set t_Co=256
set background=dark
colorscheme atom
syntax on
```

When I run `:colorscheme` in vim it returns `atom` but still with no color/syntax highlight at all.

What could I be missing?

Thanks!

Comment: perhaps `syntax on`?

Comment: oh, I missed that one on my `.vimrc`, I'll edit the question. Still, it doesn't work. Thanks.

Comment: Is `atom` a 256 color colorscheme, or does it use true color? Can you test with a 256 color colorscheme, and check that your `$TERM` environment variable is set to something that supports 256 colors?

Comment: Do you get colors if you remove `set t_Co=256` and `colorscheme atom` (i.e. just by using `syntax on` (setting `background` is optional))?

Comment: As I was not sure if atom was a 256 color colorscheme. I've tried with a different theme: [One Dark](https://github.com/joshdick/onedark.vim). My terminal supports 256 colors, but I couldn't make it work.

Comment: @melpomene I'm getting the colors, but just a few, not as in the color scheme screenshot.

Comment: fwiw, the `gui..` highlighting attributes in atom are pervasive (looks like all of them).  These are specifically for gvim and not for terminal vim.

Comment: Hi @PatrickBacon, that makes sense, I thought I could use them interchangeably. I'll look for a vim theme for terminal vim only. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The colorscheme you are trying to use only works with GUI Vim (GVim/MacVim) or *maybe* with TUI Vim *but only if* your terminal supports true colors *and* if your Vim is built with that feature *and* if you `:set termguicolors` (and possibly other hacks).

See `:help 'termguicolors'`.

Also, the `README.md` is not called `IGNOREME.md` for a good reason:

> Currently Atom is ***GVim only***. I tend to use the default colours when (infrequently) in a terminal. If you have a strong desire for added terminal support leave me a comment, drop me an email or even better: send me a pull request!

(Emphasis mine.)